# perl DateTime and non-existent time user input because of DST clock forward

Tags: perl, datetime, dst

In a scenario where we know the timezone of the user and the date but the time is input by the user in a textbox (i.e. a calendar where an user selects the date but types the time), after it is properly parsed and we know the hours and minutes, how should we deal wih a non-existent time because of DST clock forward (eg. 02:00 does not exist because of clocks are turned forward 1 hour) in order to pass it -at least an existent hour- to DateTime->new();?

```
use DateTime;
$dt = DateTime->new(
    year   => $year_userinput,  #2016
    month  => $month_userinput,  #03
    day    => $day_userinput,  #27
    hour   => $hour_userinput,  #02
    minute => $minute_userinput,  #30
    second => 0,
    time_zone => $timezone_userinput,  #Europe/Berlin
);
```

> Error: Invalid local time for date in time zone: Europe/Berlin

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: I wouldn't let the user enter invalid dates, i.e. reject them, and internally only use UTC.

Comment: @PerlDog In this scenario users can not input a valid date because they have to select them but they can type the time in many different ways which they are parsed. Of course if they type 53:69 it is rejected, but if they type 02:10 during a DST change, how can we know that such a time does not exist? Use UTC internally is helpful for operations with dates but the problem here is that the input is directly wrong because of the mentioned reason.

Comment: @mob what type of question is this if not programming related?

Comment: I meant _time_, not _date_, sorry for that. But _who_ rejects times like `53:69`? Can't you make that party also reject `02:30`?

Comment: @PerlDog the thing is that 53:69 is always a non-valid time that can be easily detected because of a wrong format (for example with a regex). In the 02:30 case the format is correct but it does not exists because of the fact that once in a year in many locations around the world the clock moves forward e.g. from 02:00 to 03:00.

Comment: Just to add a little pepper to the dish: What do you do with the "backing up" hour when the TZ returns from DST? - Moral of the story: any input of a local time is subject to doubt unless it is made with a well-understood convention of the underlying TZ. This specification includes the times when the DS switches occur, and can be used to validate and, ultimately, convert user input into UTC.

Comment: @laune You're so mean! ;-) But right. Perhaps one should have thought about this problem not just the night before it arises.

Comment: @laune In this scenario the user input data (including date and time) is not used anymore much before the TZ returns from DST

Comment: @Zillo I thought this is about detecting and refusing incorrect time-of-day entries. What has the time of the use of this data got to do with telling right from wrong? Ot are you just worried about booking wake-up calls?

Comment: @laune In my previous comment I was just trying to answer your question about the "backing up" hour when the TZ returns from DST. Actually a booking wake-up calls app from where the user (which can use any TZ) can select a day from a 10 days calendar but they freely type the time in a textfield (parsed afterwards) does not seem to be a bad example of the real case. As said before the problem arise when the user choose to receive the call a correct day but in a time that does not exist because of time is moved forward X hours/minute (generally 1 hour) due to DST related changes.

Comment: "how should we deal wih a non-existent time because of DST clock forward" Inform the user that the time they entered is invalid and ask them to enter a valid time.

Comment: How to handle bad inputs depends a lot on context, of which you provided none. Most of the time, the action is aborted and an error message is provided.

Answer (score 0):

As you go into Daylight Savings, there's no problem.  Assuming DLS starts at 2am on a given day in the fictitious time zone, ATZ (a timezone) with an offset of N hrs, then the three seconds commencing one second before 2am are timestamped;

```
1:59:59 ATZ +N
3:00:00 ADZ +(N+1)
3:00:01 ADZ +(N+1)
```

...and when coming out of Daylight savings ...

```
2:00:00 ADZ +(N+1)
2:00:01 ADZ +(N+1)
...
... about an hour later
...
2:59:59 ADZ +(N+1)
2:00:00 ATZ +N
2:00:01 ATZ
```

There appears to have been an earlier "2:00:01" but that included an offset of (N+1)  - or was in the timezone ADZ - whereas this one is in ATZ (N).  The DateTime module raises the issue like this:

### Ambiguous Local Times

*Because of Daylight Saving Time, it is possible to specify a local time that is ambiguous. For example, in the US in 2003, the transition from to saving to standard time occurred on October 26, at 02:00:00 local time. The local clock changed from 01:59:59 (saving time) to 01:00:00 (standard time). This means that the hour from 01:00:00 through 01:59:59 actually occurs twice, though the UTC time continues to move forward.*

To avoid the issue, you are going to have to always include the timezone or offset when creating time objects. To do that, you need to use the date (you said you had it) to detect that it is end-of-DLS day and, if the user has chosen a time within the critical hour, you're going to have to prompt for "is that 2:30am ADZ or 2:30am ATZ?" or something similar.  Likewise, if it's start-of-DLS, your interface has to refuse entries referencing the critical hour.

Earlier in the doco for DateTime, there's the suggestion - for performance reasons - of determining the local timezone once and then using it throughout your app;

```
our $App::LocalTZ = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'local' );

... # then everywhere else

my $dt = DateTime->new( ..., time_zone => $App::LocalTZ );
```

... but this is going to leave you vulnerable to the issue again.  Since your interface is going to have to know its start-of-DLS day or end-of-DLS day, you can set and use $App::LocalTZ as advised and then override with the specific, prompted-for Timezone if it's end-of-DLS day.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Also, the 3 seconds around the DST change would be 01:59:59 ATZ, 03:00:00 ADZ, 03:00:01 ADZ when entering and 01:59:59 ADZ, 01:00:00 ATZ, 01:00:01 ATZ when leaving.

Comment: That was careless of me - thanks for the tip.  That is what I meant to type but I copied each line and focussed not the zone, offset and seconds and forgot the hours.  Why doesn'tit aanswer the question?  When calling the constructor, you have to always supply the zone.

Comment: The question is, what should I do when a user enters an invalid time? (e.g. 02:00:00 ADZ on the first day of DST in your example) The OP is already passing the time zone in the constructor.

Comment: Ive tried to make it clearer.  Thank you for your constructive, useful and accurate criticism.